# What is the fundamental difference between these two sentences

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

He donated a million dollars for keeping the tigers alive.
He donated a million dollars to keep the tigers alive.

Comment: They use different words.

Comment: @Matt Эллен thanks for adding the tag. I googled the meaning of both.

Comment: What did you find out?

Comment: @tchrist Now I see the real difference :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any supporting context, the inferences that can be drawn here are fairly subjective, but here (for what it's worth) are mine:

> He donated a million dollars for keeping the tigers alive.

= He donated a million dollars in order to pay for their upkeep.

---

> He donated a million dollars to keep the tigers alive.

= The tigers were about to die, and he donated a million dollars in order to save them from death.

Comment: I could also read "for keeping..." as he donated the money as a sort of reward/payment for good work.

Comment: Here it was correct to use the both gerund and infinitive, although meaning was slightly different. But with most verbs only one could be used. Which to use comes with practice.

Comment: @miltonaut Yes in this case the meaning is fairly clear, but in a different context the construction could be ambiguous; e.g. *He awarded a prize for winning the 100 metres*. It is not clear if the race has yet taken place or not, and whether the prize is for the person who did win, or the one who will win.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the nuances of meaning are very slight, if any.

Comment: What about the general case?

Comment: @parv - I don't think that's a useful question here: the specifics of the context will be very important for governing the implications that can be drawn from how the verb is used.